# how to fetch bulk data from php to flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

How to retrive the bulk data from php to Flash?

Ex: got a bulk data from php to like this format|(name|age|sex|address|MobNo|TelNo),need to split and assign the value to proper variables.how to split and assign the value to perticular variable

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [AMFPHP](http://amfphp-v1.silexlabs.org/) to help with the heavy lifting.

** edit **

Here is a [nice looking flash tutorial on AMFPHP](http://flash-creations.com/notes/servercomm_remoting_amfphp.php) and also a flex tutorial of [using AMFPHP with flex](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/as3flexdb/). Choose your poison wisely!

Comment: do you have any example program? if you have please send me that example.

Comment: I used google to search up a couple quick examples (I'd advise the same). I added two that I found- one for flash and one for flex. FYI the flex one is written by **Sephiroth**. He has been around a while and is quite knowledgable.